# Changing an non-numeric list to a numeric one?

Tags: python, list

These are previously defined.

```
def get_service_code(service):
    return str(service[0])

service_106_data = filter_routes(bus_stations, "106")
service_106 = make_service(service_106_data, "106")
#print(get_service_code(service_106))  --> should return 106
```

bus_stations here is a txt file that contain a list of numbers like this

```
106,1,1,43009
106,1,2,43179
.
.
.
106,2,1,03239
106,2,2,03211
.
.
.
106,2,50,43171
106,2,51,43009
```

Then this is also previously defined

```
def get_route(service, direction):
    return str(service[int(direction)][0])

print(get_route(service_106, '1'))
```

should return this

```
['43009', '43179', '43189', '43619', '43629', '42319', '28109', '28189', '28019', '20109', '17189', '17179', '17169', '17159', '19049', '19039', '19029', '19019', '11199', '11189', '11401', '11239', '11229', '11219', '11209', '13029', '13019', '09149', '09159', '09169', '09179', '09048', '09038', '08138', '08057', '08069', '04179', '02049', 'E0200', '02151', '02161', '02171', '03509', '03519', '03539', '03129', '03218', '03219']
```

Suppose now the direction **'1'** is changed to a non-numeric number such as **'A4'**, how do I write my code such that **'A4'** is turned into **'1'**?? The below code will not work for 'A4' but it works for '1'

```
def make_service(service_data, service_code):
    routes = []
    curr_route = []

    first = service_data[0]  #('106', 'A4', '1', '43009')
    curr_dir = first[1]  # 'A4' --> #how do I change this to '1' ? 

    #additional line no. 1    

    for entry in service_data:
        direction = entry[1] #A4
        stop = entry[3]  #43009

        if direction == curr_dir:
            curr_route.append(stop) #[43009]
        else:
            routes.append(curr_route)   #[[]]
            curr_route = [stop]         #[43009]
            curr_dir = direction        #A4    
            # addition no.2

    routes.append(curr_route)   #[43009]

    #modification
    return (service_code, routes)  #("106", [43009])


 service_106 = make_service(service_106_data, "106")  
                # for e.g make_service(('106', 'A4', '1', '43009') , "106"))
```

`print(get_service_code((service_106)))`   --> expected return is 106

Comment: Question is bit confusing, can you summarise it like this is Input, expected output and what you tried.

Comment: input is for e.g make_service(('106', **'A4'**, '1', '43009') , "106"))   Then output should give me 106. Thank you @sjcipher

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an ID number to each unique element in your tuple service_data, or a list
by assigning each element as key in a dictionary, dict_. The function below, to_IDS will set 
all the elements in service_data with an IDnumber in the dictionary dict_.

```
service_data = ('106', 'A4', '1', '43009')

dict_ = {}

def to_IDS(service_data, dict_):
    ids_from_service_data = [(dict_.setdefault(i, len(dict_)))for i in service_data]

    return ids_from_service_data, dict_

print to_IDS(service_data, dict_)

Output: [0, 1, 2, 3], {'1': 2, '43009': 3, '106': 0, 'A4': 1})


Alternative solution;

service_data = ['106', 'A4', '1', '43009']

service_code = None

def make_service(service_data, service_code):
    routes = []
    curr_route = []

    first = service_data[0]  # will be 106, corresponding to index 0('106') in service_data
    service_data[1] = 1  # 'A4' --># changes value on index 1 (A4) to value 1
    curr_dir = service_data[1]   # curr_dir is index 1(A4 in service_data

#additional line no. 1    

    direction = service_data[1] #direction is service_data1

    stop = service_data[-1]  # ends at last position in list, -1

    if direction == curr_dir:
        curr_route.append(stop) #[43009]

        print curr_route
    else:
        routes.append(curr_route)   #[[]]
        curr_route = [stop]         #[43009]
        curr_dir = direction        #A4    
            # addition no.2

    routes.append(curr_route)

    service_code = service_data[0]
    return (service_code, routes)  #("106", [43009])

print make_service(service_data, service_code)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. However I am not suppose to define a new function here instead add in a few lines into the make_service function such that it works when my service_data is('106', 'A4', '1', '43009')  @user1749431

Comment: You can add this part ids_from_service_data = [(dict_.setdefault(i, len(dict_)))for i in service_data] in your make_service function where you have your comment #Additional...,and add a dictionary  dict_ = {} either as a parameter or inside the function after the list corr_routes =[]

Comment: Thanks again for the reply, I'm not really sure how this dictionary function work as we did not learn it in class. Is there any other simpler way to solve this question ? @user1749431

Comment: I've added an additional modification of you code which is simpler. Since it seems you're after fixed index positions, for instance you want routes to be a list which takes the last item in service_data, 43009, then you don't need a for loop; for event in service_road:. This part; service_data[1] = 1  changes A4 in service_data to 1

Comment: Thank you for helping me with this. However maybe I'm not very clear with my question here. Here is what we have to do "For example, suppose the route data for a hypothetical bus service can be given with directions ’A4’ followed by ’A2’ instead of ”1” and ”2” by default. We could refer to the list of directions [’A4’, ’A2’] to choose which route we want." So supposedly this code should work with when '2' is replaced with 'A2'. So I don't think it will be acceptable to write **service_data[1] = 1** as it maybe seen as hard coding. @user1749431

Comment: However after seeing u write service_data[1] = 1, I got an idea. Is there anyway to write it such that service_data[1] = to something that links to my bus_stations.txt ??

Comment: Also we are not suppose to modify the code here but only to add at the # places and modify the last return ans. Thank you so much again @user1749431

Comment: You can loop in the direction list +1 for i in range(0,len(route)): next_word = direction[i+1] service_data[index] = next_word

Comment: hmmm... I'm not suppose to create another new loop instead work on the loop that was given and add lines at the #add to make the code work. @user1749431

Comment: To loop for entry in service_data: you will need to define range if you want to loop +1 in the direction list, that is from A4 to A2. So for event in range(0,len(service_data)): will start the loop counting from index 0 in service_data,that is '106' and then you want it to continue counting, +1, to next item so next_word = direction[event+1] takes the next value in the direction list, A2, and finally the service_data[index], for instance index 1, is replaced with the next value, in this case 42 from directions in the variable next_word. Which results in  ['106', 'A2', '1', '43009']